# Why am I getting a syntax error on my $or $and query?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

Mongo keeps giving me syntax error on this line;

```
existingVideo = self.request.root.db.videos.find_one( { '$or' : [ { '_id' : ObjectId( video["serverVideoID"] ) } , '$and' : [ { '_id' : serverAuthorID } , { 'clientGUID' : video['clientGUID'] } ] ] })
```

but I can't see what's wrong with it. It looks valid to me, but can anyone spot the error here?

Comment: `{ '$or' : [ { '` are you sure your array is closing correctly ?

Comment: you need to enclose entire $and:.. expression in {} i.e. add { before $and and put } between ] and ] at the end.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky if you re-write my line in an answer I'll give you the green check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing one set of `{ }` around the $and clause.

Your query should be:

```
existingVideo = self.request.root.db.videos.find_one( 
{ '$or' : 
   [ 
     { '_id' : ObjectId( video["serverVideoID"] ) 
     } , 
     {'$and' : 
           [ { '_id' : serverAuthorID } , { 'clientGUID' : video['clientGUID'] } 
           ] 
     } 
   ] 
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this...but why does the $and need to be wrapped in {} but not the $or (other than the first {} anyway)?

Comment: the first { does "wrap" $or expression into a JSON document. then $or takes an array of JSON documents (of which {$and:[]} is one).